# Testing a belongs_to relationship in Rails with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a model called Page that has many Paragraphs. This all works but I thought it was about time I had some tests. For reasons, I need a count of all the paragraphs a page has, +1 so I know how to number the next paragraph. I do this with a count_paragraphs method in my model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :paragraphs

  def count_paragraphs
    paragraphs.count + 1
  end
end
```

So far so simple. This works fine in my controller, where I use it to create the next paragraph.

```
@paragraph = @page.paragraphs.create(body: para_params[:body], num: @page.count_paragraphs)
```

As mentioned this all works. But in testing, this does not work:

```
it 'has a paragraph count of 1' do
    expect(subject.count_paragraphs).to eq 1
end

it 'successfully counts paragraphs' do
  subject.paragraphs.new(body: "hello", num: 1)
  expect(subject.count_paragraphs).to eq 2
end
```

The first test passes, the second does not.  It always returns 1. When I binding.pry the test, each new paragraph shows up if I do `subject.paragraphs` but if I binding.pry in the model, `paragraphs` just comes back `[]`. So I am misunderstanding something about the model relationship.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't the method be called `next_paragraph_number`?

Comment: that is a much better name, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-count) does:

> Count all records using SQL.

So it only counts records that have been persisted.

You could achieve this by calling `create` instead of `new`:

```
subject.paragraphs.create(body: "hello", num: 1)
```

Or you could use [`size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-size) instead of `count` which also counts in-memory objects:

> If the collection hasn't been loaded, it executes a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query. Else it calls `collection.size`.

Comment: So when binding.pry into the model, is there any way to see the paragraphs that are in-memory and not persisted, as `paragraphs` returns `[]`?

Comment: You can use `subject.paragraphs.to_a.count` in your test.

Comment: @PaulHarker how do you "binding.pry into the model" exactly?

Comment: If I just put a `binding.pry` in the model, rather than the test, say.

Comment: @PaulHarker maybe you end up in a different instance?